# Showing that $(1-a^{-k})^{n-k} < e^{-(n-k)/a^k}$ for $a>1$ and $n>k>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I came across this inequality $(1-2^{-k})^{n-k} < e^{-(n-k)/2^k}$ in *The Probabilistic Method* by Alon and Spencer. Although I have shown it by taking natural logs of both expressions and finding that $\ln(1-2^{-k})<-2^{-k}$ whenever $k>0$, I am not satisfied with this approach and wanted to prove it by starting with the left expression and arriving at the right by some insightful manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the identity
$$
e^x>1+x
$$
for $x\neq 0$ and hence
$$
e^{-a^{-k}}>1-a^{-k}
$$
so that
$$(e^{-a^{-k}})^{n-k}>(1-a^{-k})^{n-k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $e^x>1+x$ for $x\neq 0$. Hence
$$
e^{-1/a^{k}}>1-\frac{1}{a^{k}}.
$$
Take the $n-k$-th power to both sides.